# Mongoose - creating and saving a document, then saving new document with its id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a user schema that looks like this:

```js
const userSchema = new Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
        trim: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    role: {
        type: String,
        default: 'customer',
        enum: ['customer', 'farmer', 'admin']
    },
    user_id: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    }
})
```

Additionally, I have another schema that would be called `customer` and looks something like this:

```js
const customerSchema = new Schema({
    company: String,
    contact: String,
    ...etc
})
```

Now what I'd like to do is on the creation of the `User` document, create and save a new `Customer` document, and then save it's _id to my `User` document's `user_id` field.

The post request would look something like this:

```js
// POST - USER REGISTRATION
router.post('/register', function (req, res) {
  const { email, password, role } = req.body

    const user = new User({ email, password, role,
    user_id: new Customer({
      company: req.body.company,
      contact: req.body.contact,
      ...etc (rest of data)
    })})


    user.save(function(err) {
      if (err) {
        res.status(500)
          .send("Failed to register. Please try again.")
      } 
      else {
        res.status(200).send("Registered.")
      }
    })
})
```

While this seems to create a `Customer` object **(there's an ObjectID under user_id)**, the customer isn't saved to the database (naturally since `.save` isn't called). 
My original approach here was to have a user_id variable set to null, then have the customer create & save itself, and then set the `user_id` variable to the `customer._id` value, but this didn't work as `user.save(func(err))` would have a `null` user_id value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just try like this

```
router.post("/register", async function (req, res) {
  try {
    const { email, password, role } = req.body;
    let customer = new Customer({
      company: req.body.company,
      contact: req.body.contact,
    });
    let resultCustomer = await customer.save();

    const user = new User({
      email,
      password,
      role,
      user_id: resultCustomer._id,
    });

    await user.save();
    res.status(200).send("Registered.");
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send("Failed to register. Please try again.");
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked. I also changed it so that customer is only saved once the user document is saved.